# nuget packages versioning comparison

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

When I install a Nuget package X that depend on package D version >= 0.0.2.0.
And I already have the D package version 0.0.10.0 installed. Is it going to remove the existing D version and install the 0.0.2.0 or keep the version 0.0.10 since its newer?

Is version 0.0.10.0 is >= 0.0.2.0 in nuget or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [NuGet doc](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning), NuGet uses the rules of the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org) spec, which states that:

> Each element MUST increase numerically. For instance: 1.9.0 -> 1.10.0 -> 1.11.0.

Comment: now this is strange. when I do `Install-Package mypackage` it iinstalls 0.1.15.1 but when i do `Install-Package mypackage -Source mypackagesserver` it installs 0.1.9.9 so i guess this is a bug from nuget.